# Why is n.__name__ an attribute error when type(n).__name__ works?

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

```
n = 20
print n.__name__
```

I am getting an error as `n` has no attribute `__name__`:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

But `n` is an instance of the `int` class, and `int.__name__` gives a result, so why does `n.__name__` throw an error. I expected that because `n` is an instance of class `int`, it should have access to all attributes of that class.

Comment: "Because n is an instance of class int and it should have access to all attributes of int class" - that's not how it works. Python searches the class dicts of all classes in `n`'s Method Resolution Order for a `__name__`, but `int.__name__` doesn't come from an entry in `int.__dict__`.

Answer (score 8):

`__name__` is not an attribute on the `int` class (or any of its base classes):

```
>>> int.__dict__['__name__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '__name__'
>>> int.__mro__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> object.__dict__['__name__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '__name__'
```

It is an attribute on the **metaclass**, `type` (it is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), so is bound to the `int` class when accessed on `int`):

```
>>> type(int)
<type 'type'>
>>> type.__dict__['__name__']
<attribute '__name__' of 'type' objects>
>>> type.__dict__['__name__'].__get__(int)
'int'
```

Just like attribute look-up on an instance can also look at the class, attribute lookup on a class looks for attributes on the metaclass.

Attributes on the metaclass are not available on instances of the class.