# Python object, where is `__name__` stored?

Tags: python, object, attributes

I am confused as to where `__name__` is stored within a Python object.

For example, take Python `str`:

```
In [1]: hasattr(str, "__name__")
Out[1]: True

In [2]: getattr(str, "__name__")
Out[2]: 'str'

In [3]: "__name__" in str.__dict__
Out[3]: False

In [4]: "__name__" in list(dir(str))
Out[4]: False
```

You can see from `[1]` + `[2]` that `str.__name__`, that it has the value `"str"`.  However, I can't find where it's stored by using `dir()` and `__dict__`.

I know I am missing something, but from all my reading I can't figure it out.  Can you please help me?

**Places Looked**

From these questions:

1. [python __getattr__ and __name__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9751339/11163122)
2. [Why do python instances have no __name__ attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14514838/11163122)

   - Thank you to everyone for pointing #2 out

```
In [5]: str.__class__.__name__
Out[5]: 'type'

In [6]: "hi".__class__.__name__
Out[6]: 'str'
```

One can see a `str` *instance* has `__name__ = "str"` stored within `__class__`.

Where is `__name__ = "str"` within the *class* `str`?

Thanks in advance for the help!

**Later Edit**

Turns out this was a duplicate.  The answer (as stated in the comments) is:

```
In [1]: type.__dict__['__name__'].__get__(str)
Out[1]: 'str'
```

And the reasoning can be found in these questions:

- [Setting a class __name__ declaratively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49781234/11163122)
- [Why is n.__name__ an attribute error when type(n).__name__ works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45064509/11163122)

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for linking the very useful question!  However, the marked duplicate does not answer my question, which is where in `str` class is `"str"` being returned from when one says `str.__name__`?

Comment: O.P:  the result "str" is resolved via the metaclass + descriptor protocol.  Try `type.__dict__['__name__'].__get__(str)`.

Comment: Okay thank you everyone, I am surprised those questions/answers didn't come up in my searching.  Thank you @wim for posting a TL;DR answer, and I added links to other useful questions.